# Leverage Browser Caching, Header Expires and Etags don't works

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, header, etag

I know there are already a lot of posts that talk about my problem. But, I tried several modifications to leverage browser caching, header expires and Etags (on PageSpeed and Yslow) but it doesn't work.

I made every modification I've found on the web to my .htaccess file. I made a lot of modifications in my headers in PHP too. Nothing works.

Here's the actual source code of my .htaccess :

---

```
AddType text/javascript .js

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2692000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|css|js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
```

---

For information about my server, you can look at it here : http://www.akioz.com/info.php

Comment: So what does "Nothing works" mean?  You need to be specific about what is not working.

Comment: You should be able to use something like Chrome's Inspector on the Network panel to see if these headers are being sent.

Comment: `IFModule` might be saying *yeahh.... I do not have the module, so I'll skip this*. Remove the IFModule, if you get a server error, turn on `mod_expires`